# Android : Programatically get the path/resource of an image in an ImageView

Tags: android, image, imageview

```
ImageView image = ((ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageView1));
```

How can I programmatically get the path/resource of that image? Thanks.

PS : I know I can set it this way :

```
image.setImageResource(resource)
```

Comment: the source you mean the content of the imageiew?

Comment: @blackbelt Sorry, I've corrected the question.

Comment: I don't think that's possible as an ImageView uses a `Bitmap` or a `Drawable`, not a `File`.

Comment: It's imposible. You could subclass ImageView a keep a String reference to the path

Comment: you want get image path from sdcard in mobile ?

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say you can get its path, but you can get its URI by this way:

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your_packagename/" + R.drawable.your_image_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in this way :

```
//Add image path/resource to the tag
ImageView image = ((ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageView1));
image.setImageResource(R.id.yourImage);
image.setTag(R.id.yourImage); //also can be done via xml.

//Get image path/resource from the tag
ImageView image = ((ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageView1));
Integer imageId = (Integer)image.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the exact path for an image , that is stored in drawable.

you can use this to get drawable

```
 getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imageView1);
```